# Uploading csv file and save in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one problem when I try to save some data into my database, imported from a CSV file (uploaded).

My environment is about a classroom reservation. I have the following code for my model Reservation:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'csv'

  belongs_to :classroom

  validates :start_date, presence: true
  validates :end_date, presence: true
  validates :classroom_id, presence: true
  validate :validate_room

  scope :filter_by_room, ->(room_id) { where 'classroom_id = ?' % room_id }

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file, headers: true ) do |row|

      room_id = Classroom.where(number: row[0]).pluck(:id)

      Reservation.create(classroom_id: room_id, start_date: row[1], end_date: row[2])
    end
  end

  private
    def validate_room
      if Reservation.filter_by_room(classroom_id).nil?
        errors.add(:classroom_id, ' has already booked')
      end
    end
end
```

The CSV file comes with these three headers: "classroom number", "start date", "end date".
Note that "classroom number" header came from a column of classroom table.
My job is to get the classroom.id using the "number" and create the row in the database of the reservation table.

Ok, but the problem is when I get the classroom_id in "self.import" method and print on the console, he exists. When I use the scope to filter the classroom_id, he is empty.

Expect I've expressed myself like I want.

Sorry for my bad English :/

Edit: Discovered that `classroom_id` before `Reservation.create` become `nil` when I use inside the create method. If I use `row[0]` works, but I need to use `classroom_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, I forgot to use `.first` after `pluck(:id)` method.

The pluck method returns a value wrapped in an array:

```
room_id = Classroom.where(number: row[0]).pluck(:id).first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ where 'classroom_id = ?' % room_id }
```

Should be

```
{ where 'classroom_id = ?', room_id }
```

Comment: the problem remains :/

If put `puts room_id` below `room_id = Classroom.where(number: row[0]).pluck(:id)`, the room_id will appear.

But, if I put `puts classroom_id` below `def validate_room`, the variable is empty.

Comment: I discovered that the room_id exists, but when I put into "create" method, he turns to "nil", but if I use the row[0], works. Unfortunately, row[0] isn't the value I have to use.

You know something about what can I do?